# Cannot refer the binding project in Xamarin.iOS project

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I have created a Xamarin.iOS binding project. My binding project compiles successfully. Then I added Xamarin.iOS project. Structure is like this.

[image]

Then I created a class and tried to import my binding project like this.
[image]

But then I get the following issues.

[image]

What would be the reason for these? Please help me to resolve these issues.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, do you have a try with building it, and it will build successfully in this status?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I added the .dll to my xamarin.ios project. then these issues eliminated. But still cannot run on the device. It saysLibrary not loaded Reason: image not found (Xcode's device log)

Comment: Could you show project reference manager view ? **Right click Project- >Add ->Reference ->Check whether choose Binding lLibrary.**

Comment: I got the dll from the binding project and added to the xamarin.ios project. Your wayt was the one I tried before but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Okey , this should be another probem about library method not got image.Suggest that open an new question with detail info .You can sharing .a file methods in new question, problem will be found quickly. :)

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018752/xamarin-ios-app-not-launching-on-the-device

Comment: Thanks, Having seen the new one,I will check it.